# How I can Dockerize my web api on windows

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-web-api

Docker is a full development platform for creating containerized apps, and Docker for Windows is the best way to get started with Docker on Windows systems.

- Start your favorite shell (cmd.exe, PowerShell, or other) to check your versions of docker and docker-compose, and verify the installation.

  `PS C:\Users\Docker> docker --version`
- Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

  `PS C:\Users\Docker> docker-compose --version`
- docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions is not very specific but it appears that you are trying to containerize an asp.net web app, Here is a basic clue to what you want to accomplish by using docker.

Docker is a linux containers system means it's based on linux kernel and by installing docker in windows you are installing a linux guest machine to built your containers in and you will customize your containers to forward ports that will serve your app development from inside the container to your host machine, So basically How this is going to happen? after installing docker first docker needs a base image(linux image) to run your containers from, so a great place to find docker images is [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com), so also for a basic scenario you need:

1) Pull an image.

2) Run a container based on this image.

To accomplish **number 1**: we will use [microsoft dotnet official docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) as an example.

```
docker pull microsoft/aspnetcore
```

docker pull: will pull the `dotnet:latest` image from docker hub, `:latest` is a tag specify the latest stable release of dotnet means if you want another runtime version you will use `docker pull dotnet:runtime` from the above dotnet official docker hub link you will find tags under `Supported tags`

To accomplish **number 2**: we need to run a container by using this image.

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name firstwebapptest microsoft/aspnetcore
```

docker run: will create a container name `firstwebapptest` based on `microsoft/aspnetcore` forwarding the container port `80`to the host port `8000` and all of that will run as a detached mode `-d`

And now check your browser `localhost:8000`

This is a very basic scenario using the docker command line tools.
So another way to accomplish this scenario is by using a **dockerfile** you will find `How to use this image` in microsoft dotnet official docker hub link, It assumes that you already in your app directory that contain your compiled myapp.dll. What will you do is create a file called `dockerfile` in this directory and write this inside:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

FROM: base image that we already pulled

WORKDIR: that will be the directory inside the linux container

COPY: `. .` the first `.` is copying your host directory content inside the container the second `.` is your guest directory in that case will be `/app`

ENTREYPOINT: is the linux command that will run once this container is up and running in that case `dotnet myapp.dll` means you are running the command `dotnet` from the linux container inside the `WORKDIR` `/app` with all your host directory app structure that contains your compiled `myapp.dll.` that we already copied it `COPY . .`

so now we have the dockerfile all what we need is to build and run it.

```
docker build -t secondwebapptest .
docker run -d -p 8001:80 secondwebapptest
```

docker build: will build a container named `-t secondwebapptest` from `.` the dot refer to the dockerfile that you just built and that you are already in the working directory otherwise you have to specify a path to the docker file by using `-f` but that is not our case.

docker run: will run the container that already been created that named `secondwebapptest` based on forwarding the container port `80`to the host port `8001` and all of that will run as a detached mode `-d`.

And now check your browser `localhost:8001`